# Concatenate different variable if exist in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to concatenate different variable if exist and return the result.
But I need to separate the value by "-" and return only the variable with value.

So I have this:

```
  var test = "";
  var test1 = "";
  var test2 = "";
  var test3 = "";

  var checkTrue = "Rightt";
  var checkFalse = "Wrong";
  var checkWord = "Helloo";
  var checkWord2 = "Bye";

  if(checkTrue === "Right"){
    test = "This is right"
  } else {
    test = "";
  }

  if(checkFalse === "Wrong"){
    test1 = "This is wrong"
  } else {
    test1 = "";
  }

  if(checkWord === "Hello"){
    test2 = "The word is hello"
  } else {
    test2 = "";
  }

  if(checkWord2 === "Bye"){
    test3 = "The word is hello"
  } else {
    test3 = "";
  }

  var result = test + " - " + test1 + " - " + test2 + " -" + test3;
  console.log(result);
```

So I think I need to verify before my var result, if the different variable exists ?

Thank for your help

Actual result:

```
 - This is wrong -  -The word is hello
```

Expected result :

```
This is wrong - The word is hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With anything where you want a separator between string values, I find it easier to use `Array.prototype.join()` which will only place the separator between actual values.

It then becomes easier as you have a single `results` array that can be joined, only adding values you want rather than testing each of those variables you no longer need.

By pushing on to an array you can also get rid of all those `test` variables too.

```js
const results = [];

const checkTrue = "Rightt";
const checkFalse = "Wrong";
const checkWord = "Helloo";
const checkWord2 = "Bye";

if (checkTrue === "Right")
  results.push("This is right")

if (checkFalse === "Wrong")
  results.push("This is wrong")

if (checkWord === "Hello")
  results.push("The word is hello")

if (checkWord2 === "Bye")
  results.push("The word is hello")

const result = results.join(" - ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: hmm pushing so that no filtering is needed is quicker and you answered first.. ok ok I'll remove my answer and support this one

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test = '';
const test1 = 'This is wrong';
const test2 = '';
const test3 = 'The word is hello'

const result = [test, test1, test2, test3].filter(value => value).join(' - ');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do the tests and you've changed the initial variable values!

Comment: Yes but I understand his solution :)

Comment: @phuzi The values are obviously for a simplified demonstration. What do you want to say?

Comment: Does it really need simplifying? You're actually making the solution more complicated with extra testing of every value. Better to push wanted values on to an array first and remove the `filter` completely.

Comment: To my understanding, OP is asking about 'concatenate' but not 'check'. Therefore, I think only the last 2 lines of the original code should be changed and that's why I have simplified all the lines above.